# Extjs 5 Validation - Validate after 4 characters entered

Tags: regex, validation, extjs

I am currently trying to validate a string in the format

1 Character (A-Z) and 3 Characters (A-Z 0-9) (alpha character followed by 3 alphanumeric)

This is my custom vtype:

```
customalphanumeric: function(
    return (/^([A-Za-z]){1}([A-Za-z0-9]){3}$/).test(v);
},
customalphanumericText: 'Please enter 1 Alpha character followed by 3 alphanumeric characters',
customalphanumericMask: /([A-Za-z0-9])/
```

When I enter any letter into the box the Text shows up "Please enter 1 Alpha character followed by 3 alphanumeric characters".

How do I make it wait for 4 characters to be entered?

I had tried this:

```
if (v.length == 4) {
    return (/^([A-Za-z]){1}([A-Za-z0-9]){3}$/).test(v);
}
else {
    return true;
}
```

but this allows phrases that are less than 4 characters. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is gonna work the way you want, because if the error is not displayed until it reaches 4 characters it means the form is valid until that point and whoever is using your form will be able to submit it.

What you can do is add a minLength: 4 property and get all the validations displayed correctly:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'MyApp',

    launch : function() {
        var customRegEx = /^([A-Z]){1}([A-Z0-9]){3}$/i;
        Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
            customtest: function(val, field) {
                return customRegEx.test(val);
            },
            customtestText: 'Please enter 1 Alpha character followed by 3 alphanumeric characters',
            customtestMask: /([A-Z0-9])/
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
            title: 'Test Panel',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                vtype: 'customtest',
                minLength: 4
            }]
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  This is a better solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much had it.

```
if (v.length == 4) {
    return (/^([A-Za-z]){1}([A-Za-z0-9]){3}$/).test(v);
}
else {
    //return true;
    return false;
}
```

You could change the text given back in the else statement as well